# Backup users and mailboxes using `virtualmin backup-domain --feature`

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, virtualmin

Does anyone know the commands to backup the mailboxes and users for virtual domains in Virtualmin using command line?

I can't find any detailed documentation apart from saying to use `--feature`.

I know how to backup everything using:

```
for i in $(cat domains.txt); do virtualmin backup-domain --domain $i --dest /home/backup/$i.tgz --all-features ; done > /var/log/domains-backup.log
```

But I don’t want to backup everything for all domains, just the mailboxes & users.